# Does MeteorJS Mini Mongo use disk? or just memory?

Tags: meteor, minimongo

I would like to know if MeteorJS's `mini mongo` (just to be clear, on the client) retrieves its data from memory (RAM) of from disk (maybe local storage). Also if it write to disk the objects received. I'm concerned about performance (and app responsiveness).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is all in-memory. Thus very fast and recreated on every complete app reload.

Sometimes you want more persistent behavior and this is where packages come into place. An example of what you can do can be demonstrated in [ground:db](https://atmospherejs.com/ground/db) package. This package lacks good conflict resolution but one can imagine building an advanced version of it.

Answer (score 2):

It is entirely memory based. Afaik there is no caching in localStorage but even if there were, current implementations only allow for about 5 MB of storage per domain, which would therefore only ever be used for faster startup.

Web applications don't have access to disk in general due to security issues.